# I Am Using NgbCalendar and on Runtime need to change it from NgbCalendarGregorian to NgbCalendarIslamicUmalqura

Tags: angular6, ng-bootstrap

As far as i know in Angular 6 for NGBCalander we need to change the Class in Providers Section of the Module.ts to change the calendar type between NgbCalendarGregorian to NgbCalendarIslamicUmalqura. But how to achieve this on Run time based on Language selections of the user is something i am having trouble to achieve. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can provide the calendar implementation at the component level, not necessarily at the module level. BTW, that's what the examples in https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/calendars do. Read their code. So, if you want to switch at runtime, you can simply use an ngIf to swicth between a component using a gregorian calendar to a component using an islamic one.

Comment: how is it that i can toggle through providers on run time ?

Comment: You can't. That's not what I suggested. I suggested switching between two **components**: one displaying a gregorian calendar, and one displaying an islamic one.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch between two components: one display a gregorian calendar, and one display an islamic using ngIf or ngSwitch